# aspnet_regsql not working at all

Tags: asp.net, database, asp.net-membership, sql-server-express, mdf

I would like to create the ASP.NET User database template on a database of my own, because I'd like to fully untegrate the user system with the rest of my DB. As I've read, i needed to use the aspnet_regsql tool. I put all the options (because my database is running on SQLEXPRESS and is in an mdf file in my project's folder). the program starts and seemingly runs without any errors, however, when I open the database after that, not tables or stored procedures have been added.

One more thing: I did one more test. I intentionally gave the -d option a wrong mdf file address, and surprisingly, the program "finished" correctly, yet no file was crated or modified whatsoever.

Comment: We cannot guess what you are doing wrong. You need to post both the full path to your db, and the command line that you are using. Then maybe we can get to the bottom of it.

Comment: I managed to do it. What I did was to attach my mdf file to the core SQLEXPRESS system. Then, I was able to use the aspnet_regsql wizard which accomplished the job. My problem with the wizard before was that  the wizard did not allow me to use a database that wasn't a part of the core SQLEXPRESS system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question was resolved. Please, see my own comment on the first one